# Unit testing writing to HttpWebRequest's request stream

Tags: .net, unit-testing, httpwebrequest

I'm back filling some unit tests in our app at work, and came across the following method.

```
public virtual void WriteBodyToRequestStream(HttpWebRequest webRequest, byte[] redirectBodyBuffer) {
    var requestStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream();
    requestStream.Write(redirectBodyBuffer, 0, redirectBodyBuffer.Length);
    requestStream.Close();
}
```

I'm trying to write a simple test that inserts some text in the stream. The problem I'm having is figuring out how to verify the text after it's written into the stream. Here's what I have so far.

```
[Test, Ignore("not working yet")]
public void Should_write_to_request_stream()
{
    var request = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/") as HttpWebRequest;
    request.Method = "POST";
    var encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
    var bytes = encoding.GetBytes("testing");
    _helper.WriteBodyToRequestStream(request, bytes);

    var stream = request.GetRequestStream() as MemoryStream;
    var result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());

    Assert.AreEqual("testing", result);
}
```

When I run this test, the `stream` var is null.

Comment: what you have there is not a Unit Test; it's an Integration Test

Comment: What is the _helper object and what does it do, can you show source code?

Comment: @Bronumski The rest of the class is unrelated to the method in question, so it's irrelevant in this context.

Comment: Not if your question is about why the request stream is null and you are calling the method WriteBodyToRequestStream on the helper object with the request you are trying to test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do you really need to pass `HttpWebRequest` to your `WriteBodyToRequestStream` method? You really don't care about the `HttpWebRequest` its more the stream you are interested in:

```
public virtual void WriteBodyToRequestStream(Stream requestStream , byte[] redirectBodyBuffer) {
//var requestStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream(); remove this line.
requestStream.Write(redirectBodyBuffer, 0, redirectBodyBuffer.Length);
requestStream.Close();
}
```

This makes your method easily testable (whether its a unit test or integration test I will leave up for discussion ;P)